# cannot load such file -- foreman/cli (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

> I got one error message while running following command.I use Proxy.is this a problem with proxy?please help me.Thanks in advance.

```
C:\Users\rajitha\java-getting-started>foreman
C:/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `
require': cannot load such file -- foreman/cli (LoadError)
        from C:/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_requi
re.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Heroku/bin/foreman:8:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

use `heroku local` instead. It's the replacement for foreman.

Comment: hei after running that one I got one error->   C:\Users\rajitha\java-getting-started>heroku local
Installing Heroku Toolbelt v4... done
Installing plugin heroku-local... done
Downloading forego-0.16.1 to C:\Users\rajitha\.heroku... done
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | Error: Could not find or load main class Main